# Pass varying arguments to unknown form at runtime

Tags: c#

I use the following code to call and open a form at runtime (sourced from this forum). The name of the form depends on user input:

```
    // Method
    private void ShowForm(string formToCall)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType("MyForms." + formToCall);
        var form = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;
    }

    // Call
    ShowForm("StationDef");
```

Now, some forms take arguments and some not.  I can add a parameter with a null default value to the ShowForm() method which will then only change when an argument actually gets passed, but I cannot figure out how to change the ShowForm() code to accept an argument in that case.

Something like this does not work:

```
    private void ShowForm(string formToCall, object arg = null)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType("MyForms." + formToCall);
        var form = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form(arg);
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am unclear what the question is. Do you want `arg` to allow 0 or 1 parameters? Or should it also support more than 1? What **exactly** do you want to do with `arg`?

Comment: If you use the `JavaScriptSerializer` then you can pass two strings in: ArgType, Arguments and get the dynamic ability without having to grapple with C#. On both sides of the handshake your using C#, but you're sending as JSON to make the exchange easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work because `as` requires a type name, not a constructor-call.

```
var form = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form(arg);
```

What you can do instead is passing your arguments to the `CreateInstance`-method like so:

```
var form = Activator.CreateInstance(type, arg) as Form;
```

I'd suggest you parse that arg to `object` so you do not interfere with other overloaded versions of `CreateInstance`.

[Further Reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k6dfxfk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This code does not produce an error, suggesting that CreateInstance is happy, but it does not display the form.  An int with a value of 1 is passed as the argument.


               object[] ar = { arg };
               var xtraForm = Activator.CreateInstance(type, ar) as XtraForm;

Is something obviously wrong here?

Comment: The parameters you have to pass have to be the same as the ones in the constructor, so if your `Form` has a constructor that has an array of objects, this would be fine, but I guess what you want is what I wrote above: Pass the arguments directly.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try something like:

```
private void ShowForm(string formToCall, object[] args)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType("MyForms." + formToCall);
    var form = Activator.CreateInstance(type, args) as Form;
}
```

You can even make it more "friendly" like this

```
private void ShowForm(string formToCall, params object[] args)
```

And use it like this:

```
ShowForm("MyForm", arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Thanks very much.